# Rails - Order by the average of an association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am struggling to add a sorting feature in my fake imdb copycat website.

I have movies that have many reviews through an association. Unfortunately I can't find how to order the @movies object by review average for the index page.

Obviously, this

```
includes(:reviews).order("reviews.rating_out_of_ten desc")
```

doesn't work has it only order by the first review of each movie. 
How can I write it so that it order by the average of all associated reviews ??

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Average of which field you required in this??

Comment: Not sure I understood the question but I want an average of the rating_out_of_ten field of the reviews associated with a movie

Answer (score 2):

In order to sort by the average movie score, join to the reviews table and use the `avg` function in the order by clause i.e.

```
Movie
    .select('movie_id, movie_name, avg(reviews.rating_out_of_ten)')
    .join(:reviews)
    .group('movie_id, movie_name')
    .order('avg(reviews.rating_out_of_ten) desc')
```

Comment: why `movie_name` is needed in group?? i think movie_id is enough

Comment: I added movie_name to the group because it's in the select. most databases have this as a requirement

Comment: Do I still need to put includes(:reviews) ? The select doesn't work because:
"no such column: reviews.rating_out_of_ten"

Comment: @FabienAlbi the `join` should be enough